# REG QUERY Key with a space in the name

Tags: linux, windows, spaces, rsh, remote-registry

I am new to linux. Please help !!

I am trying to read the windows registry key entry on a remote (windows) system using the below rsh command which has a space in the folder name. Kindly let me know how to resolve this.

rsh <"remote_ip"> REG QUERY HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\VMware, Inc.
ERROR: Invalid syntax.
Type "REG QUERY /?" for usage.

Thanks,
Rajesh

Comment: The first step is to figure out how the command should be formatted, exactly, in order to permit this, when executed natively from an MS-Windows command line. It's logically impossible to figure out how to execute a command if you don't really know what the command should be.

Comment: perhaps quoting just the filename is enough : REG QUERY HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\"VMware, Inc."

Comment: Imsteffan.. I tried it. Did not work

Comment: Sam.. Thanks for ur reply.  On windows command line, we need to mention the key name in quotes. It works there, but not on a remote machine..   On windows:-   PS C:\Users\Administrator> REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\VMware, Inc."  

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\VMware, Inc.\VMware Drivers

Answer (score 1):

When the path contains names with space, use quotes as shown

REG QUERY "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\VMware, Inc."